# Pandas dataframe adding zero-padding before the datetime

Tags: python, pandas

I'm using Pandas dataframe. And I have a dataFrame `df` as the following:

```
time      id
-------------
5:13:40    1
16:20:59   2
...
```

For the first row, the time `5:13:40` has no zero padding before, and I want to convert it to `05:13:40`. So my expected `df` would be like:

```
time       id
-------------
05:13:40    1
16:20:59    2
...
```

The type of `time` is `<class 'datetime.timedelta'>`.Could anyone give me some hints to handle this problem? Thanks so much!

Comment: Hi, the type `timedelta` is used to describe the difference between times, rather than times themselves. Is your column meant to be a time stamp, rather than a time delta?

Comment: @smj type(df['time][0]) gives me this. Yes, I want the time column to be time stamp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `pd.to_timedelta`:

```
df['time'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['time'])
```

Before:

```
print(df)

       time   id
1   5:13:40  1.0
2  16:20:59  2.0

df.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 2 entries, 1 to 2
Data columns (total 2 columns):
time    2 non-null object
id      2 non-null float64
dtypes: float64(1), object(1)
memory usage: 48.0+ bytes
```

After:

```
print(df)

      time   id
1 05:13:40  1.0
2 16:20:59  2.0

df.info()
d<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 2 entries, 1 to 2
Data columns (total 2 columns):
time    2 non-null timedelta64[ns]
id      2 non-null float64
dtypes: float64(1), timedelta64[ns](1)
memory usage: 48.0 bytes
```

Comment: @Scoot Boston Thank you so much! it did adding a zero before time, but it has additional time information associated with it. So 5:13:40 changes to 0 days  05:13:40.000000000